# SOAP java client HTTPS/SSL

Tags: java, soap, https, soap-client

Im trying to call a web service over https , the administrator send me the WSDL file and certificates for my server :

```
myserver.der
myserver.p7b 
myserver.pem
myserver-bundle.pem
```

I installed the certificate myserver.der :

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias myserver -file myserver.der
```

Then, using wsimport, I generated the stubs.

Before calling the web service, my client is doing this :

```
String javaHomePath = System.getProperty("java.home");
String keystore = javaHomePath + "\\lib\\security\\cacerts";
String storepass= "changeit";
String storetype= "JKS";

String[][] props = {
      { "javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore, },
      { "javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keystore, },
      { "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", storepass, },
      { "javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", storetype, },
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < props.length; i++)
      System.getProperties().setProperty(props[i][0], props[i][1]);
```

Questions :

1) I don't know what to do with the other files (.p7b ; .pem) ?

2) It seems that the handshake works , but im getting this error :

```
 com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent    HTTP status code 407: Proxy Authentication Required
```

Thanks for Help

Comment: Using jdk1.8.0_25, when I run `keytool -help` I don't see `-import` as an option.  I tried: `keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias myserver -file myserver.crt` and that seemed to work.  It looks like keytool still recognizes the `-import` option since `keytool -import` didn't throw an error.

Comment: Note, that by running this command in Windows 7, the key was saved in C:\Users\USERNAME\.keystore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through this link to understand the difference between different certificate formats - [Different Certificate Formats](https://myonlineusb.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/what-are-the-differences-between-pem-der-p7bpkcs7-pfxpkcs12-certificates/)

You can go through this link here - [Java SOAP client with certificate authentication](https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luis-rodriguez-fernandez/2014-07-java-soap-client-certificate-authentication)

create keystore like this:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file myserver.p7b -keystore keystore -storepass <mypasswd> -alias "myalias"
```

**Note** that myalias MUST be the same as the one used when the key was generated.

You can also verify if keystore has certificates

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

To debug the ssl handshake process and view the certificates, set the VM parameter `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

PS: Also, go through this link which might help you resolve Proxy Authentication Required error - [Proxy authentication in Java](http://blog.vinodsingh.com/2008/05/proxy-authentication-in-java.html)

Comment: Wich one of the files (.der ; .p7b ; .pem ; bundle.pem) i have to add to the client.jks and cacerts.jks ?

Comment: @user986586, How did you create your keystore?
`keytool -import -trustcacerts -file myserver.p7b -keystore keystore -storepass <mypasswd> -alias "myalias"`. Also try keeping the storepass and private key pass as same just to try if that works.

Comment: I can't install the .p7b , im getting this error :

 java.lang.Exception: The entry it's not an X.509 certificat